# Cocos2D-X Linker Error; what am I missing?

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, linker, cocos2d-x

I'm following a Cocos2D-X tutorial for iOS on XCode 5 and the instructor started off by creating a bunch of classes and header files. Among those is a header file called "Utils.h" that contains some static functions

```
class Utils
{
public:
    static Game* gameLayer();
    static HUD* hudLayer();
    static cocos2d::CCLayer* layerWithTag(int tag);
    static cocos2d::CCSize s();
    static cocos2d::CCAnimate* getAnimationWithFrames(int from, int to);
    static void scaleSprite(cocos2d::CCSprite * sprite);
    static float getScale();
    static void setScale(float s);
    static float getArtScaleFactor();
    static void setArtScaleFactor(int s);
};
```

The `s()` functions is defined in Utils.cpp to just `return CCDirector::sharedDirector()->getWinSize();`

Now, the problem is: when the `s()` function is called in my main menu scene (`Utils::s().width` for instance), I get this error "Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)" and "Symbol(s) not found for architecture i386". However, when I deleted the `s()` function definition from Utils.cpp and just added the function in the class in the header file so that it becomes

```
//Utils.h
class Utils
{
public:
     .......
     static cocos2d::CCSize s()
     {
         return CCDirector::sharedDirector()->getWinSize();
     }
     ......
```

It compiles without an error...

Why is it that I get this error when the function is in the cpp file instead of the header file? I know my problem is already solved but it's just driving me crazy

Thanks! :)

Edit: I thought this was a given but to be clearer, in the main menu scene I included Utils.h not Utils.cpp

Comment: Got a link to that tutorial? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please note that such errors also appear when you have declared a function in one file (say Cpp) and not in the .h file.
Most common reason that i have seen is because one declares a function in the .h file but forget to give the implementation.

Comment: I am sure I declared the function in the .h file and implemented it in the cpp file. Maybe the implementation in the cpp wasn't correct somehow? I guess I'll check on that. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: I'd like to see how you were declaring it in the cpp file.

Comment: Well in the .h file I got this `static cocos2d::CCSize s();` and .cpp I declare it like this

    `cocos2d::CCSize s()
    {
       return CCDirector::sharedDirector()->getWinSize();
    }`

Comment: This gives me an error when I try to use `Utils::s().width` for instance in the main menu scene

Comment: Ah! did u try  
cocos2d::CCSize Utils::s() { return CCDirector::sharedDirector()->getWinSize(); } 
?
As you see, there wasn't a Scope resolution operator before s() in the code u gave... That would've been the issue.

Comment: Wow that actually worked! I should have noticed that.
Wish I could vote up your answer but my reputation is still low..
Thank you so much!